# percent match within the same table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join, right-join

Below I have an MySQL database where `"id"` is just an id for each row. "question" shows the id of the question. There are four questions, `11, 12, 13 and 14`. For every question the user has four answer options `(1,2,3 and 4)` which is stored in the `"answer"` column. The `"user"` column indicates what user who answered. In this example we have user 10, 11 and 12

```
id      question    answer      user
1           11          2       10  
2           12          2       10
3           13          3       10
4           14          4       10
5           11          2       11
6           12          2       11
7           13          4       11
8           14          1       11
9           11          2       12          
10          12          2       12  
11          13          1       12
12          14          1       12
```

Let's say that user 10 is the reference user which means that I want to know how well user 10 matches with the others. Using SQL **and/or** php code how can I match the answers of the users such that I get the matches in percent with the highest **percent** shown first. So in this example I'm looking for something like.

```
        user     percent    
1       11       50%
2       12       75%
```

I'm not sure if this is possible all the way with only SQL. Maybe a bit of php is needed to convert the count to **%** for instance.

Comment: Assuming that was right, you'd probably be better off going with a mix of SQL and PHP.

Comment: Nice question but do you have tried anything till now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got your desired output
Try this:

```
SELECT * ,round(count(*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM `list` where user=10)*100) as
 pecentage FROM `list` as l where l.answer=(SELECT m.answer FROM `list` as m
 where m.user=10 and l.question=m.question) group by (l.user) order by pecentage
```

It will produce out put as

[image]

and you can add `l.user!=10` in where condition if you don't want `user 10` value.

Comment: Great!! Works perfectly!! Awesome job!! And where to add the "l.user!=10" exactly?

Comment: SELECT * ,round(count(*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM `list` where user=10)*100) as
 pecentage FROM `list` as l where l.answer=(SELECT m.answer FROM `list` as m
 where m.user=10 and l.question=m.question) and l.user !=10 group by (l.user) order by pecentage